# uwp ink handwriting recognition failed at windows 10 iot core

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I download a sample of ink handwriting recognition at link:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-topic-specific-samples/archive/uwp-ink-handwriting-reco.zip
but it run failed at windows 10 iot core.always show "no recognition results" after recognize.how to solve it?

I try to debug the code.the code have no exception.

[image: show "no recognition results"]

Comment: You should install the ink recorgnition in your win10.

Comment: It run at win10 successfully.But I want it run at win10 iot core.

Comment: Which build of Windows IoT Core were you testing the sample on?

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT v.10.0.15063.0

Comment: @CodeLife, please try to upgrade to 16299 or later version. Build 16299 improved ink support on Windows 10 IoT Core.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT Thank you.I have a try.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT I use v.10.0.17134.1 version to run it.but have a new ploblem "System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'” at the code IReadOnlyList<InkRecognitionResult> recognitionResults =
                        await inkRecognizerContainer.RecognizeAsync(
                            inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer,
                            InkRecognitionTarget.All); How to solve it?Thank you

Comment: @CodeLife, yes, i confirmed the sample on 17763, it gets the same error.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT OK.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The ink recognition dependent system. You should sure the system installed the  Handwriting recognition

1. Go to Settings > Time & language > Region & language.
2. Select Add a language.
3. Select a language from the list, then choose the region version. The language is now listed on the Region & language page.
4. Click the language and select Options.
5. On the Language options page, download the Handwriting recognition engine (they can also download the full language pack, speech recognition engine, and keyboard layout here).

See: [Recognize Windows Ink strokes as text and shapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/convert-ink-to-text#international-recognition)

Comment: Windows 10 IoT core have no these setting.

Comment: @CodeLife, i have confirmed that sample [Ink analysis sample (basic) (C#)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-topic-specific-samples/archive/uwp-ink-analysis-basic.zip) works fine on Windows IoT Core, but the text recognizer does not work on Windows IoT Core. You can use Feedback Hub app to post this issue.